# Which visa type do I require for my indirect flights?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit

I'm traveling from Kosovo to Norway but my flight there is through Germany and on the way back through Germany and Austria.

Do I need only Single entry or Multi?

Comment: Kosovo passport

Answer (score 3):

Norway, Germany and Austria are all in the Schengen area, so as far as visas and border controls go you'll be making **only one entry** (Kosovo to Germany) and one exit (Austria to Kosovo).

Any travel between Germany, Norway and Austria counts as domestic for border-control purposes.

Comment: So , Single Entry - when I apply for the Visa  ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: @Prishtina: Yes.